# how to resolve this query, do I need a function?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, max

I have to find the  maker that produces more printers than laptops or pcs.

```
 maker   |  type    |  models
 HP      |  laptop  |   7
 Lenovo  |  PC      |   5
 Sharp   |  Printer |   13
 Kyocera |  Printer |   8
 Dell    |  Laptop  |   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this in many ways.  One method using correlated subqueries is:

```
select maker
from t
where type = 'Printer' and
      models > (select t2.models from mytable t2 where t2.maker = t.maker and t2.type = 'laptop') and
      models > (select t2.models from mytable t2 where t2.maker = t.maker and t2.type = 'type');
```

One thing you can do with this approach is readily extend it to any number of models . . . with a tweak:

```
select maker
from t
where type = 'Printer' and
      models > (select max(t2.models)
                from mytable t2
                where t2.maker = t.maker and t2.type <> 'Printer'
               ) ;
```

Or, if you like:

```
select maker
from t
where type = 'Printer' and
      models > all (select t2.models
                    from mytable t2
                    where t2.maker = t.maker and t2.type <> 'Printer'
                   ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and filter with a having clause:

```
select maker
from mytable
group by maker
having 
    sum(case when type = 'Printer' then models else 0 end) 
        > sum(case when type = 'laptop' then models else 0 end)
    and sum(case when type = 'Printer' then models else 0 end) 
       > sum(case when type = 'PC' then models else 0 end)
```